# Workflow Rule to Timestamp created/updated datetime in specific format

Tags: datetime, workflowrule, format

I want to update the value of a text field on the Order object using Workflow Rule

Field Update should be a timestamp of the current user creating and updating the record

> The datetime stamp should be in the format:
>
> YYMMDDHHmmSS

```
for example:
171031121052
```

How i will do the field update work?

Comment: `DATETIMEVALUE(expression)` instead of `expression` you should select any `DateTime` field from Insert Field button.

Comment: I dont want that format 171031121052 this format only i want

Comment: I'm happy to help with the formula, but it depends on the locale of the org/users. Are the locales (and therefore the date formatting conventions) the same for all affected users?

Comment: TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) & IF(LEN(TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW())))) & IF(LEN(TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) like this format i want

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through workflow? Are you trying to update some text field, with current Date and Time in format YYMMDDHHmmSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For US-based users (it might depend on the user locales), the formula in the workflow field update should read:

```
RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),4),2)
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),7),2)
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),10),2)
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),13),2)
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),16),2)
&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(YourDateTimeField__c),19),2)
```

It's ugly, but it gets the job done with the limited text functions available in Salesforce's formula editor.

Comment: Create a Workflow Rule and select "Evaluate the rule when a records is: " *created*,  then add a Workflow Action of type "Field Update" with the option to "Use a formula to set the new value"

Comment: What date/time information are you trying to capture and save in this format? Is it the record's created date/time or some other field on the Order?

Comment: In that case replace each occurrence of *YourDateTimeField__c* in the formula with *LastModifiedDate*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53372/discussion-between-brent-bow-and-user36188).